# Am unable to install Kubuntu onto laptop from USB

Tags: system-installation, usb, kubuntu

I'm trying to install Kubuntu onto my laptop, to replace its current distro. I used the dd command to transfer the ISO from my computer to the USB, and everything seemed to be working fine. However, even though I selected the USB from BIOS it still boots into the current distro... which I no longer want! I've tried several times already, selecting different options each time, to no avail. Is there anyway to determine what went wrong?

Comment: Are you selecting the right drive boot priority in BIOS?

Comment: Yes! Because of how many times I've tried to boot it, I selected all available options. Nothing worked!

Comment: Do you know a program 'Unetbootin'? It's another boot disc/usb drive creator.

Comment: I've never been able to get that one to work. The last time I tried to use it, it didn't see the installed (and freshly formatted) USB drive!

Comment: What is usb drive's filesystem and size?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to access a Windows computer, I'd recommend using [win32diskimager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/).

It has never failed me when making bootable USB drives.

Comment: I don't know that one, so will check it out, ta. I personally no longer have a Windows computer, so I'll have to see if my dad will let me borrow his... though he's currently away and won't be back for a few days!